# Altering stored procedure/cursor to update table

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC FilmLength
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Name CHAR(40) ,@Minutes INT
DECLARE Filmcursor  CURSOR 
       FOR (SELECT FilmName, FilmRunTimeMinutes from tblFilm)

OPEN filmcursor
FETCH NEXT  FROM filmcursor  INTO  @Name, @Minutes
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    IF @Minutes < 120           PRINT (@Name + 'is a SHORT film')
    ELSE IF @Minutes <150   PRINT (@Name + 'is a MEDIUM Length film')
    ELSE                            PRINT (@Name + 'is a LONG film')
    FETCH NEXT  FROM filmcursor   INTO  @Name, @Minutes
END
CLOSE filmcursor
DEALLOCATE filmcursor
END
```

Instead of printing, I need it to update and add the short, medium, long labels to a column in the same table named Duration. I've tried changing PRINT to SET but it doesn't go through.

This is what I was using, but it wasn't going through. I was using

```
Use Movies
Execute FilmLength
Select *
from tblFilm
```

to execute

```
USE Movies
GO
ALTER PROC FilmLength
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Minutes INT, @Duration Char(6)
DECLARE Filmcursor  CURSOR 
       FOR (SELECT FilmRunTimeMinutes, Duration from tblFilm)

OPEN filmcursor
FETCH NEXT  FROM filmcursor  INTO  @Name, @Minutes
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    IF @Minutes < 120           SET @Duration = 'SHORT'
    ELSE IF @Minutes <150       SET @Duration = 'MEDIUM'
    ELSE                        SET @Duration = 'LONG'
    FETCH NEXT  FROM filmcursor   INTO  @Name, @Minutes
END
CLOSE filmcursor
DEALLOCATE filmcursor
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on what you've told me about your table and it's columns, you don't need a cursor (they're frowned upon), this can be accomplished much easier with a simple update/case statement.

```
USE movies 

UPDATE tblfilm 
SET    duration = ( CASE 
                      WHEN ( filmruntime < 120 ) THEN 'SHORT' 
                      WHEN ( filmruntime BETWEEN 120 AND 150 ) THEN 'MEDIUM' 
                      ELSE 'LONG' 
                    END ) 

SELECT * 
FROM   tblfilm
```

Hopefully this is what you need.  I'm assuming your table columns are as following.

FilmName VARCHAR(MAX)
FilmRunTime Numeric(18,0)
Duration VARCHAR(MAX)

If your column datatypes are different let me know.

Comment: This didn't seem to go through for me either. I've added more info to my question above

Comment: Okay, so without knowing the column names in your tblfilm table it's difficult to write the code for you since I'm just guessing.  Pease provide a list of the columns in tblfilm.

Comment: Another thought, you said you need to update the values stored in tblfilm, well if you run this more than once it's going to keep appending "short, medium, Long" to the values unless you have some sort of data indicating that you've already updated these.  For example your SP might take in a date and only update values with a date greater than XXX, or maybe after running the update, you have another column called, updatedwhen that holds a date time value, if this is null then it updates the records with null, otherwise it skips records that are not null. Does that make sense?

Comment: The Columns in question in tblfilm are FilmName, FilmRunTime and Duration. As of now, Duration is empty (filled with Nulls) and I want to take the values from FilmRunTime (aka minutes) to help label each film Short, Medium or Long. Does this help?

Comment: Curly.Q have you had a chance to review the answer I provided?

Comment: Just looking to see if you've reviewed the answer I provided.